# Adding image to a div using JQuery

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to create a poker web app using an poker library (http://tairraos.github.io/Poker.JS/)

One of the methods to render a card image is using this function:

```
getCardImage: function(size, suit, point) {
            var image = document.createElement('img');
            image.src = this.getCardData(size, suit, point);
            return image;
},
```

It creates an image using canvas and places inside an img tag. I've been trying to place it inside a div, like:

```
$('#flop').append(Poker.getCardImage(60, 'hearts', 'j'));
```

but to no avail. The only way it renders normally is using:

```
document.body.appendChild(Poker.getCardImage(100, 'h', 'Q'));
```

I really run off of ideas of how to pull this out. I've tried many JQuery methods and nothing worked. I see on the network tab of chrome that the image is created using a base64, but when I try to place it inside a div, nothing appears. Only if appends to the end of the body. 
Can someone lend me a help here?

tnx

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just have to change your `getCardImage` function to return a jQuery Element instead of an HTML element.  Try this:

```
getCardImage: function(size, suit, point) {
    var image = '<img src="' + this.getCardData(size, suit, point) + '" />';
    return $(image);
}
```

Then your jQuery append should work:

```
$('#flop').append(Poker.getCardImage(60, 'hearts', 'j'));
```

Comment: Try building the element as a string instead of a DOM element. Updated answer.

Comment: They way you are doing it should work. Are you sure there is a div on the page with with id=flop? Try `document.getElementById("flop").appendChild(...)` and see if that works.